# Group By and CASE query in LinQ

Tags: linq, t-sql, case, grouping

How can I write this query in LINQ:

```
   SELECT Name,
          READY =     max(CASE TrDet.tracktypeid WHEN 7 THEN 1 END),
          AVAILABLE = max(CASE TrDet.tracktypeid WHEN 2 THEN 1 WHEN 5 THEN 1 END)
   FROM  PENDINGAPPROVAL Apr
   JOIN  TRACKS Tr           ON Apr.TrackId = Tr.Id
   JOIN  TRACK_DETAIL TrDet  ON Tr.Id = TrDet.TrackId
   GROUP BY Tr.Name
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi--Stack Overflow is not a free code conversion service.  You may get lucky and someone might do this for you, but you'll typically get a better response if you start converting it yourself and then post here when you have a specific problem or question about the conversion or the results you're getting..

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question you asked, but this gets the answer you want:

```
var results=context.PENDINGAPPROVAL.Select(p=>new {
  Name=p.Name,
  READY=p.Tracks.Any(t=>t.TRACK_DETAILS.Any(td=>td.tracktypeid==7))
  AVAILABLE=p.Tracks.Any(t=>t.TRACK_DETAILS.Any(td=>td.tracktype==2 || td.tracktype==5))
});
```

Comment: hehehehe.....these are not the droids you are looking for